# How to load test with simultaneous users?

Tags: apache, jmeter, load-testing

In jMeter
I have a test plan with 100 virtual users. If i set ramp up time to 100 then the whole test takes 100 sec to complete the whole set. That means each thread takes 1 sec to perform for each virtual user. Meaning that each thread is carried out step by step. However, each thread is carried out after completion of previous one.

Problem: I need 100 users accessing the website at a same time , concurently and simultaneously. I read about CSV but still it does act step wise dosent it. OR if I am not clear about it. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into "classic" situation described in [Max Users is Lower than Expected](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/147922-max-users-is-lower-than-expected) article.

JMeter acts as follows:

- Threads are being started according to the ramp-up time. If you put 1 there - threads will be started immediately. If you put 100 threads and 100 seconds ramp-up time initially 1 thread will start and each 1 second next thread will be kicked off.
- Threads start executing samplers upside down (or according to [logic controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
- When thread doesn't have more samplers to execute and more loops to iterate - it's being shut down.

So I would suggest adding more loops on Thread Group level so threads kicked off earlier kept looping while others are starting so finally you could have 100 threads working at the same time. You can configure test execution time either in Thread Group "Scheduler" section or via [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller).

Another good option is using [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) which provides easy way of configuring your load scenario.